# Disable MenuItemLabel Zoom feature on touch in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am working in cocos2d-x 3.3 which is similar to any version after v3.0.
I want to create a label in which the amount of text can vary and in also want a callback whenever it is touched.
I have created it in following way:

```
    Label* questionLabel = Label::create("", "Dimbo Regular.ttf", 36);
    questionLabel->setColor(Color3B(190, 30, 45));
    questionLabel->setDimensions(900, 120);
    questionLabel->setHorizontalAlignment(TextHAlignment::LEFT);
    questionLabel->setVerticalAlignment(TextVAlignment::CENTER);
    questionLabel->setString(questionString);
    MenuItemLabel* questionMenuLabel=MenuItemLabel::create(questionLabel, CC_CALLBACK_1(PreAssessment::questionPressedCallback, this));
    questionMenuLabel->setPosition(520,516.5);
    auto menu=Menu::create(questionMenuLabel,NULL);
    menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
    addChild(menu,1);
```

The label is created and it is also hitting the callback method.
The only problem that i am facing is that whenever i touch the label it gives me a scale/zoom effect until the touch doesn't end.

I want to disable that zoom/scale effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass the MenuItemLabel class and override the **selected()** method

```
class NoZoomMenuItemLabel : public MenuItemLabel{
public:

    static NoZoomMenuItemLabel *create(Node*label, const ccMenuCallback& callback);
    virtual void selected() override;

};

// .cpp
NoZoomMenuItemLabel * NoZoomMenuItemLabel::create(Node*label, const ccMenuCallback& callback)
{
    NoZoomMenuItemLabel *ret = new (std::nothrow) NoZoomMenuItemLabel();
    ret->initWithLabel(label, callback);
    ret->autorelease();
    return ret;
}

void NoZoomMenuItemLabel::selected()
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Usage :

```
NoZoomMenuItemLabel *questionMenuLabel = NoZoomMenuItemLabel::create(questionLabel, [](Ref *pSender){
    log("Click !");
});
```